# Any way of integrating search functionality in Shopify hydrogen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm unable to find any relevant shopfront API for adding searching functionality in Shopify Hydrogen. Can someone tell me any way of integrating search functionality using Shopify hydrogen???

Answer (score 0):

[`products`](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-04/queries/products) takes a [`query`](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-04/queries/products) string which allows you to filter by tags, title, etc. [Here's how to use the search syntax](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/search-syntax). Your query might look something like this:

```
{
  products(first:10, query:"title:The Hydrogen") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```